# Fedora lost from bootloader

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, fedora, bootloader

Initially I had Windows10 on one of my primary partitions. Then I installed Fedora on one other primary partition. Till then both Fedora and Windows were showing up in bootloader. Recently I formatted Windows Partition to install Windows7. Now, there is no bootloader is appearing to enter fedora. It is directly entering Windows. How to get Fedora back on bootloader.

My boot environment is **Legacy BIOS**

Answer (score 1):

When you reinstall Windows, the boot code on the MBR will be re-written. To get the bootloader (I assume it's grub) back you need to reinstall it again with, for example, a Fedora live medium.

Depends on whether you have a separate partition for `/boot`, the command varies. If you do, mount it on for example, `/mnt`,  in the live environment; if you don't, mount the partition for `/` there:

`mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`

Run EITHER of the following commands to reinstall grub:

`grub2-install --boot-directory /mnt /dev/sdX` (if you have a separate partition for `/boot`)

`grub2-install --boot-directory /mnt/boot /dev/sdX` (if you do NOT have a separate partition for `/boot`)